# Why does my computer shut down suddenly without any warning?

Tags: cpu, power-supply

My computer is:

- Motherboard: MSI 970a-g45
- CPU: AMD FX-8350 eight core processor 4.0 GHz
- Power Supply: TSCO 650 Watts

I bought my CPU 2 days ago. My last CPU was an AMD Athlon 460 x3 3.4 GHz.
After installing the new CPU, my power supply now shuts down suddenly without any warnings or errors.

Comment: I can't see the 8350 in the list of supported CPUS http://www.msi.com/product/mb/970A-G45.html#/?div=CPUSupport

Comment: @Tog - I found the entry within 5 seconds of looking. Here is the entry **"FX-Series Vishera FD8300WMW8KHK FX-8300"**

Comment: @Parham - If I were to hazard to guess your CPU is overheating.

Comment: @Ramhound, I also found that entry within 5 seconds. The number does not match what he has posted. Are you saying that the 8300 refers to a series that includes the 8350 because the other processors don't seem to be listed that way.

Comment: @Tog - I am indeed saying that.  I assume based on the description of the problem, the system POSTs, and thus the CPU is supported.  All I know is that the motherboard supports AM3+ processors thus the AMD FX-8350.

Comment: You didn't specify your video card, it may be that 650w is not enough power for your all of your components. Video cards can require up to 400w for themselves alone.

Comment: The PSU wattage should be enough. There are other aspects of a PSU that can make it unreliable, even if the wattage looks sufficient on paper. For example, the PSU's ripple protection may not be up to par and it may not be supplying clean power to the components. I agree with @RamHound in that it's probably the CPU overheating due to an unaligned heatsink or ineffective application of thermal paste.